# How to use correctly the associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, associations

Im doing a model association between two models that are called Resume and Province.

Where:

```
class Resume < ActiveRecord::Base
has_one :province
end
```

and

```
class Province < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :resume
end
```

at this point, everything is okay, but when I'm listing all resumes, I want to display the province name instead the province_id.

So, whats the better way to do such thing without have to perform a select for every single record?

Maybe this association is wrong.

In the Province table I have only the name and id fields.

province
- id
- name

resume
- name
- lastname
- ...
- province_id

Tell me if you need more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

controller.rb

```
@resumes = Resume.all
```

in your view:

```
<% @resumes.each do |resume| %>
  <%= resume.province.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: That's returns:
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'provinces.resume_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `provinces`.* FROM `provinces` WHERE (`provinces`.resume_id = 483) LIMIT 1

It look for an resume_id on province table that doesn't exist.

Comment: Well, following this line, I have just inverted the associations on the models and it works!

So, Resume belongs_to province and Province has_one resume.

Thank you! I'm going to consider your answer as correct.

Comment: Ah, sorry. The foreign key goes to the relations that has the belong_to, see here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association  (I see, you just found out yourself :) )